# Can anyone suggest a web framework for organising course content?

Tags: framework, user-interface, visual-design, web

I have a training course which I want to transfer from it's current version of a PDF into a website. The website will allow users to go through the course content.

Currently the training course has 10 sections and within those sections you have sub-sections.

Example:

[image]

So I wanted to know if anyone has a suggestion of any frameworks which may help me organise the content in a user friendly way? Or any other design suggestions which may achieve this goal?

NOTE: I have tried searching myself but I'm unable to find what I'm looking for. So if anyone can point me in the right direction then that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is a great framework to start with and is likely a perfect fit for your situation.

The following link is an article describing six great online coursework plugins for WP, most of them free.  The free ones are available directly from wordpress.org, which means they have been vetted and tested by the WP community.

[Online Course Plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/e-learning-plugins-for-wordpress/)

The next issue is, how to transfer all that pdf information to something usable on the web....  Adobe Acrobat has features such as Export to HTML and Export to Rich Text.  One of those should work very well.

Good luck!